# Finding and deleting Duplicate records which vary by one field

Tags: sql

I have a rates table with 18 columns. Now there are few rows in which all 17 columns have same value but differ in the 18th column(17 columns as input and 18th column being my output). I want to find out all such rows and delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your database, following SQL probably works:

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE (col1, col2, ..., col17)
IN (
  SELECT col1, col2, ..., col17
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY col1, col2, ..., col17
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

- [Demonstration on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38f71/1)
- It follows the SQL-92 Standard ([Mimer SQL-92 validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/index.tml#parser))

Comment: I want to see my result set with primary keys before deleting them.
using the above query i won't to able to that.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a query to GROUP BY the 17 fields and then see where duplicates exist.  Based on these results you could determine what to delete.

```
SELECT Field1..Field17, COUNT(Field18) AS Dups
FROM ... Table
GROUP BY Field1, Field2, Field3,.... Field17
HAVING COUNT(Field18) > 1
```

Comment: I want to see my result set with primary keys before deleting them. using the above query i would be able to see the result set but not with the primary keys.